# Sobreposição de imagens no Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estou com um problema ao tentar sobrepor uma imagem já existente no Python 3.

```
from tkinter import *
jan = Tk()
jan.geometry("500x500")
jan.configure(background="#f0f0f0")

head = PhotoImage(file = "rosto0.png")
label = Label(jan, image = head)
label.place(x=100 , y=10)

def crt():
   head2 = PhotoImage(file = "rosto1.png")
   lbl = Label(jan, image = head2)
   lbl.place(x=100 , y=10)

crt = Button(jan, text="TROCAR ROSTO", font=("Centurty Gothic",10), 
command=crt)
crt.place(x=5, y=10)

jan.mainloop()
```

Comment: Mesmo que eu coloque a imagem em posiçao diferente da outra a imagem n aparece em si mas ocupa espaço

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom dia amigo!

Resolvi seu problema aqui de uma maneira bem simples:

Usei apenas um label e quando o botão é clicado, simplesmente alterei a propriedade *file* do label: `head['file'] = "rosto1.png"`

Segue o código:

```
from tkinter import *

jan = Tk()
jan.geometry("500x500")
jan.configure(background="#f0f0f0")

head = PhotoImage(file = "rosto0.png")
label = Label(jan, image = head)
label.place(x=100 , y=10)


def crt():
   head['file'] = "rosto1.png"


crt = Button(jan, text="TROCAR ROSTO", font=("Centurty Gothic",10), command=crt)
crt.place(x=5, y=10)

jan.mainloop()
```

Se puder, testa ai e manda um feedback se resolve o seu problema.

Comment: Cara funcionou sim, mto obrigado msm, nao sabia q podia so altera o caminho no python, vlw msm

Comment: Que bom! Pode alterar qualquer atributo..